# Using a delimiter to print out "separately" all the elements of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to print out each one separately, but i cant get the last element because split() will only return the first 3 elements ?

```
var animals = "bear, lion, tiger, jaguar";

$.each(animals.split(",").slice(0,-1), function(index, item) {             
   console.log(item);
});
```

p.s. I specifically don't want to put a comma after the last item.

Thanks!

Comment: split is enough for your expected output

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `slice` over there?

This works fine by adding a space after ','

```
$.each(animals.split(", "), function(index, item) {             
   console.log(item);
});
```

Comment: How do you want them to be printed? Each in a new line?

Answer (score 0):

Add a space after , in the split.

```
var animals = "bear, lion, tiger, jaguar";

$.each(animals.split(", "), function(index, item) {             
 console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` to convert string into array. 
Use `trim` to remove spaces.

```js
var animals = "bear, lion, tiger, jaguar";

var animalsToArray = animals.split(",");

var result = document.getElementById('result');

for (i = 0; i < animalsToArray.length; i++) {
  var animal = animalsToArray[i].trim();
  
    console.log(animal);
    
    // Append to result div  
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = animal;
    result.append(element);
}
```

```html
<div id="result">


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var animals = "bear,lion,tiger,jaguar";

$.each(animals.split(","), function(index, item) {             
   console.log(item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `slice()` method your code works fine.Because the `split()` method splits your string into an array.You don't need any other method in this case.

```
var animals = "bear, lion, tiger, jaguar";

$.each(animals.split(","), function(index, item) {             
  console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Split You can done this. Try this

```js
var animals = "bear,lion,tiger,jaguar";

$.each(animals.split(","), function(index, item) {             
   console.log(item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```